# Calling Function constructor returns... Nothing. Why?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a script file which generates a webpage using a function (similar to):

```
var get_parameters = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
var json_from_get = JSON.parse(get_parameters);
var main_function = (function(json_from_get) {
    ... lots of code here
})(json_from_get);
```

I call this file from an XHR request in an inline script tag, and not directly:

```
<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', 'path/to/my/script.js', 1);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        return new Function(this.response); // -> Not working!
    }
};
xhr.send('parameter_1={"is-json":true,"can-you-believe":false}');
</script>
```

the `new Function()` doesn't work (I don't even get an error - I get **NOTHING**), and I have no clue why. I haven't tried to use `eval` since I read everywhere that EVAL IS EVIL, and I don't want to support satan. so please help me to understand how can I use `new Function` properly.

Thank you

Updating: readyState and status are okay.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you verified that you are getting a 200 response?

Comment: @Taplar Yes, the file exists See my update please

Comment: You haven’t called the function. Instead of returning it, do that. Serving a function to generate a page instead of data is kind of weird, though, and this kind of thing will still prevent you from making use of important features like restrictive Content-Security-Policy.

Comment: @Ry- how can I call it? (I'm new to `Function`)

Comment: `var f = new Function(…); f();`

Comment: @Ry- Thank you. now it works! I'm so dumb :(

Comment: Note `return` statements inside events like `onreadystatechange` arent going to be returning to anything usable by your code